# Regex replace certain strings followed by variable numbers, in a large blob of test

Tags: regex

I have a large blob of text that includes superfluous elements throughout.  I want to regex/replace the superfluous elements, so I split out the remaining elements into an array.  Here's an example:

```
Targeting Segment 12345
Platform XXX Audience ID: 23846552432410014
Targeting Segment 93823
```

The superfluous text I want to regex out is the middle line:
`Platform XXX Audience ID: 23846552432410014` (the text before the colon is fixed; the numbers are variable, and I don't want to retain those either)

How would I regex replace the constant: 'Platform XXX Audience ID: ', and then following by an indeterminate amount of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

`\d+` matches any number of digits. You must include the newline to delete the whole line:

```
Platform XXX Audience ID: \d+\n
```